# expand shell path expression in python

Tags: python, shell, path

```
path = 'foo/{bar1,bar2}'
```

How to expand to ['foo/bar1', 'foo/bar2'] as the bash shell would? I've tried glob, os.path.realpath and I don't see anything in shutil either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get bash to do it for you ;)

```
paths = subprocess.check_output('bash -c "echo foo/{bar1,bar2}"', shell=True).split()
```

Comment: Yeah, good simple idea. This is probably the best way actually unless there is some builtin shutil type thing.

Comment: won't work if your original has some spaces in it, like `some {foo1,foo2}/bar`

Comment: Ah yes. Spaces will make a mess. I can't think of a good way of fixing that - you could escape the spaces, but then the split gets the wrong items. Perhaps replace them with markers on the way in (like _ if you don't expect them to appear normally) and then do a reverse replace on the way out.

Comment: @Glenn you should use single quote and escape the string `"'%s'" % p.replace("'", "'\''")`

Answer (score 0):

There's no builtin way to do that. You'd need to write some parsing code to extract the elements.